# Do something on tap and hold with a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I know I can add an `onClick` to my TextView if I want to listen for single taps. Can I do something similar for tap-and-holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the onLongClick() method [see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html#onLongClick%28android.view.View%29)